# Correct way to use a Go project on Windows, with Gofmt mangling CRLF as it does

Tags: git, core.autocrlf, gofmt

According to this closed (works as expected) go issue [2242](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/2242) the expected behaviour of gofmt on Windows is to change all file line endings for you to cr+lf.  The behaviour on Posix systems is reverse.

With my git repo set to core.autocrlf true, or with it set to false, I still see in git commit that gofmt has modified line endings, and all files show up as modified.

I am not sure how to get out of this pit of failure.  Gofmt is alone in its insane behaviour since no other tool or editor I own does this awful thing to my files.

Comment: I think I might just be stuck with this.  I turned on autocrlf globally, then recloned the repo, and the behaviour I abhor is now mitigated.  The stupidity that is gofmt is cancelled by the egregious counter horror of autocrlf.

Comment: This is a question for the gofmt mailing list or issue tracker, is it not?

Comment: No because its as designed- For non git users like mercurial say the situation is dire